# What's the difference between objdump and Dumpbin in windows?

Tags: reverse-engineering, portable-executable

It seems both of them can dump the contents of a binary file,

then what's the difference?

Answer (score 8):

There isn't much difference.

Dumpbin is a Microsoft utility for Portable Executables (PE).

Objdump is part of the GNU binutils packages and supports lots of binary formats, including COFF and PE.

Use whichever you prefer. I use objdump because I can inspect PE files from Linux. I'd say use the one that's installed on your system: Dumpbin on Windows, Objdump on the rest.

Dumpbin might give you a slight edge concerning exploring exported symbols and stuff.